# 2019 China National Olympiad day 1 P3

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Let $O$ be the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$($AB<AC$), and $D$ be a point on the internal angle bisector of $\angle BAC$. Point $E$ lies on $BC$, satisfying $OE\parallel AD$, $DE\perp BC$. Point $K$ lies on $EB$ extended such that $EK=EA$. The circumcircle of $\triangle ADK$ meets $BC$ at $P\neq K$, and meets the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ at $Q\neq A$. Prove that $PQ$ is tangent to the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$.

my progress:
Let $M$ be the midpoint of arc ${BAC}$. Let $K'$ be the reflection of $K$ over $E$ and denote $L=AM\cap BC$. Note that $OE\perp AM$, thus $OE$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AM \implies E$ is the circumcenter of $\odot(KAMK')$. Let $X=MK\cap \Gamma$ and $Y=MK'\cap \Gamma$. Clearly $XY$ passes through $O$, by radical axis we have that $XY$ also passes through $L$.